# How to do folder redirection

Tags: group-policy

I am using the instructions found here: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=windowsserver&seqNum=61 on a windows 2008 machine.  My question is in regard to this step:

2.From the left pane, navigate to User Configuration, Policies, Windows Settings, Folder Redirection.

I don't see how to do this.  I am in the server manager and breaking down from the features expanding section.  Is there a specific GPO editor that I need to be in to make these changes or can I do it from inside the server manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this from within the Group Policy Management Console, inside or outside Server Manager:

http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2008/07/07/installing-gpmc-on-windows-server-2008-and-windows-vista-service-pack-1.aspx

http://trycatch.be/blogs/roggenk/archive/2007/07/25/windows-server-2008-amp-group-policy-management-console-gpmc.aspx

It sounds like the problem you are having is that you have not added the Group Policy Management feature in Server Manager.

Comment: I already have it installed.  That is what I meant by "features expeanding section".  Is this different from GPO editor or are they the same thing?

Comment: They are referring to the Features item in the left pane in Server Manager.  They are effectively the same console AFAIK.

Comment: Do you know how to get to "User Configuration" ?

Comment: When you Edit a particular GPO, you should see both Computer Configuration and User Configuration within the object's Edit dialog.