# User with Mandatory Profile can log in to Windows 7 but not to Windows XP

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, windows-xp, profile

I have a Windows Server 2008 domain with both WinXP and Win7 PCs. Users are usually fine to log in to either OS, but there is one user who can't login on XP. It fails to create his profile. I believe they are mandatory profiles. How can I allow this user to log in to either Windows 7 or Windows XP?

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense in its current form. From what I can ascertain, you have roaming profiles or mandatory profiles configured and a profile that works on XP doesn't work on Windows 7.

This is because Windows 7 (and Vista and Windows 8 as well) use a new profile structure. You cannot use XP-era profiles with Vista, 7, or 8 clients.

Comment: Absolutely this - the only way is to have a split estate handled with Group Policy or whatever.

Comment: So I need to check the GPO what do I need to check exactly?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you have this set up.

Answer (score -3):

There is a fair amount of info on this topic on Technet and in the Technet forums. I am not going to replicate it, but here is a [forum question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/2e3d27cf-38ec-433d-8bee-2a69a73871a5/) with a ton of good info.

What I will say is that you should use this as an excuse, if possible, to eliminate roaming and mandatory profiles.  Use [folder redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/69323/how-to-do-folder-redirection) instead. With XP clients it requires SP2 or SP3 and the [GP Client-side Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628) on each workstation.